# The house of a friend of Bob’s

Tags: word-usage, possessives, double-possessive

How do I say *(a friend of Bob’s)’s* house?

It’s like a double possesive. Bob’s friends are a class of people. *Tom, a friend of Bob’s* denotes that he is one among Bob’s friends.

Now what if I want to specify the friend’s name is *Tom*?

Which of these (if any) applies:

1. I went to a friend of Bob’s, Tom’s, house.
2. I went to a friend of Bob’s’, Tom's, house.
3. I went to a friend of Bobs’s, Tom’s, house?

What’s the correct punctuation and such?

Comment: Bob's friend's house...

Comment: I would be very likely to say (but not to write) *a friend of Bob's's house.*

Comment: *Bob's friend Tom's house*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"a friend of Bob's" means "one of Bob's friends".  Therefore, you can say

"**I've been to Tom's, one of Bob's friends.**

/or/

**I've been to Tom's, a friend of Bob's.**

You can omit the word "house". It's implicit.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways that English indicates the possessive -- with the preposition "of" (A friend of Bob) or with "'s" (Bob's friend).  The latter is called the Saxon genitive, because that's the way that Anglo-Saxon (Old English) inflected some nouns to indicate the genitive case.  *Cyning* means king in Old English, and *cynig**es*** means the king**'s** or **of** the king.

English not only kept both possessives but uses them together, which seems somewhat redundant, but which has been around for a long time.  You'll find some learned wrangling about how far back the practice goes, but it shows up in [*The Canterbury Tales*](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/CT/1:8.2?rgn=div2;submit=Go;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;q1=oon%20maximus) ca 1390.

> Oon maximus, that was an officer
>   **Of** the prefect**es**, and his corniculer,
>   One Maximus, who was an officer of the prefect's, and his aide,

This is often called the "double genitive" although *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* will sniff at you for using this term, preferring "oblique genitive" because there is only one possessive sense.

Let's suppose that Tom is the friend and he owns a house.  It may be tempting to pile more genitives on a double genitive:

> a friend of Bob's house

But this is problematic because the Saxon genitive is attached to a noun, not to a phrase.  What you're trying to say is

> (a friend of Bob)'s house

that is

> Tom's house

You'll likely be understood, but any more and you'll soon lose yourself and your reader (or listener) in the chain of possession.  And things only get worse if there are multiple friends and multiple houses.  Note that this is not a danger for "of":

> The perfume **of** the flowers **of** the garden **of** the house of a friend **of**
>   Bob.

The double possessive finds it use not in extended chains but to resolve an ambiguity.  Take the sentence

> I took Bob**'s** picture.

Are you a photographer or a thief?  For the former, you say

> I took a picture **of** Bob.

If the latter,

> I took a picture **of** Bob**'s**.

Comment: But the *'s* is not the Saxon genitive, it is the modern English clitic.  People think nothing of saying "the woman with the red jacket's car is parked illegally," where the s attaches to the phrase *the woman with the red jacket.*  Nobody in their right mind would say "the woman's with the red jacket car..."

Comment: @phoog You think that It's not the Saxon genitive because we're not speaking Anglo-Saxon?  Do you think it's not French leave unless we cross the French border?  People say a lot of things without thinking.  For instance the comment about "the woman's with."  Of course nobody says that because you can't attach a prepositional phrase to a possessive.  Did you think I was proposing that people do that?

Comment: I think it's not the Saxon genitive because it does not function as the Saxon genitive did.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive_case#English.  In other words, it is not the Saxon genitive precisely because it applies to phrases, not words.

Comment: @phoog Freud reported that a surgeon of his acquaintance objected to the psychological term "hysteria" because it could be applied to males, and the word "hysteria" came from the Greek word for "womb."  Clear yet?

Comment: @phoog Possessives formed with the clitic _’s_ in (modern) English are traditionally known as the _Saxon genitive_, despite the fact that they are obviously quite different, both syntactically and morphologically, from actual genitives in Saxon. You are quite right, though, that the statement “But this is problematic because the Saxon genitive applies to nouns, not phrases” is incorrect. The Saxon genitive **never** applies to nouns as such, but **always** to noun phrases.

Comment: The Saxon genitive applies to phrases, not nouns.  But when you try to attach *'s* to "a friend of Bob's", you end up with a double clitic, "a friend of Bob's's house". And "a friend of Bob's house" sounds funny because there's a single *'s* which is doing double duty.

Comment: The Saxon genitive is the name give to "'s" attached to a noun to indicate possession.  English doesn't have a way to attach a clitic to a phrase.  The clitic in the double genitive applies to Bob, just as the "of" governs Bob.  The phrase "a friend of Bob's house" attempts to get the clitic to take on one more duty and indicate that the Tom owns the house, running headlong in the sense of the similar construction "a friend of Bob's mother."

Comment: @deadrat: it attaches to noun phrases. Nobody would think *"her youngest daughter's dog"* means *"the youngest dog of her daughter"* rather than *"the dog of her youngest daughter"*. But when the phrase involves a possessive *"of"* (rather than just adjectives and a noun), it's ambiguous.

Comment: We may interpret the meaning this way because of the attraction of a preceding adjective to the word following, which we'll interpret as a noun right up until the sibilant.  The clitic is still attached to the noun "daughter."

Comment: @deadrat what about "the king of Spain's daughter"?  It certainly does not mean the king of a daughter of Spain.

Comment: @phoog What about a "friend of Bob's mother"?  How does that differ from "a friend of Bob's house"? And what does any of this have to do with my point?

Comment: @deadrat *a friend of Bob's mother* differs from *a friend of Bob's house* in that it is ambiguous.  The relevance of this to your point is that "applies to nouns, not phrases" is incorrect.

Comment: @phoog Grammatically, they're the same construct, and you have to rely on the contextual semantics to figure out who belongs to whom.  Once you try to pile on more genitives, you're hopelessly lost, if you weren't to begin with.  I've changed "apply" to "attach."  Happy now?  There's no way to syntactically to tag a phrase with a Saxon genitive (a term, I that I take you've given up complaining about).  All you can do is add "'s" to a noun.  What that means is a different issue.

Comment: @deadrat, I have given up complaining about "saxon genitive" but only because it appears to be accepted as a label for something that is neither saxon nor genitive.  I disagree with that, but I will not complain further.  But it is not true that "all you can do is add 's to a noun," as in "that man you met yesterday's bicycle": https://books.google.com/books?id=yoNqhym0u2sC&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=%22you+met+yesterday%27s%22&source=bl&ots=tlmPdip9RU&sig=lc5JqwPkOKfxtJCo2p9Bn7lLz1U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMIwfb5otv8xgIVidIeCh0evwT2#v=onepage&q=%22you%20met%20yesterday's%22&f=false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26326/discussion-between-deadrat-and-phoog).

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct way to write this using apostrophes to signify the possessive. You would have to say:

> I went to the house of a friend of Bob.

or

> I went to the house of Tom, a friend of Bob.

or

> I went to the house of the brother of one of Bob's friends.

As in many cases, you can determine the rule by taking the example to the extreme. In the last example above, how would you write it with apostrophes?

> I went to one of Bob's friends' brother's house.

Utter confusion! Does the *one* refer to the friend, or the house? Should it be *houses* ?

This is why you should keep the object of the verb close to the verb, and eschew nesting the possessive apostrophe.